# mongodb php: count the number of field in a subdocument

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, aggregation-framework, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter with mongodb library https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library

below is my collection "users". I want to count all the badges which has badge_slug = 100_club for userid 57b83ae9faa76bac338b4579 from users collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57b83ae9faa76bac338b4579"),
"displayname" : "test",
"email" : "test@gmail.com",
"badges" : [
    {
        "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T05:52:06Z"),
        "object_id" : "",
        "badge_slug" : "100_club"
    },
    {
        "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T06:12:14Z"),
        "object_id" : "",
        "badge_slug" : "100_club"
    },
    {
        "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T07:09:55Z"),
        "object_id" : "",
        "badge_slug" : "reader"
    }
]
}
```

what I have done is

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        "$project" => array(
            "count" => array(
                "$size" => array(
                    "$filter" => array(
                        "input" => "$badges",
                        "as" => "badge",
                        "cond" => array("$eq" => => array("$$badge.badge_slug", "100_club") )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "$group" => array(
            "_id" => null,
            "total" => array( "$sum" => "$count" )
        )
    )
);
$this->mongo_db->aggregate("users", $ops);
```

So the result should be 2 for given document.
But its returning count for all users. Where should I need to give userid condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter documents before they're passed to next stage.